# Find the $n$-th term in this series $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{5} + \frac{9}{10} - \frac{16}{17} + \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Any help with this? This is neither geometric nor arithmetic.

> Find the expression for the $n$-th term in this series:
>   $$ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{5} + \frac{9}{10} - \frac{16}{17} + \ldots$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice the numerators are the square numbers $1,4,9,16, \ldots$ and the denominator is always one more than the numerator. Since the signs alternate, we need a $(-1)^{n + 1}$-term, too.
Therefore, the $n$-th term of the series is given by
$$a_n:=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n^2}{n^2+1}
\qquad \text{with} \quad
a_1 :=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: No need to give $a_1$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

That would be $${(-1)^{n+1}n^2\over n^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution (which was already given by others here) but an extended comment on the proposed series.

Consider the partial sum

$$s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{k^2}{1+k^2}$$

The summands fail to obey the Leibniz criterion, as they don't go to $0$ for $n\to\infty$. Hence the infinite sum is not convergent by this citerion. In fact it is divergent is a special form:

The partial sum $s(n)$ oscillates for $n\to \infty$ between these two values

$$A = \frac{1}{2} (1-\pi \; \text{csch}(\pi )) \simeq 0.363985$$

and

$$B = A-1\simeq -0.636015$$

The proof starts with rewriting

$$s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{1+k^2}{1+k^2}-\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{1}{1+k^2}= f(n) - g(n) $$

with

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{2} \left((-1)^n-1\right)$$

$$g(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{1}{1+k^2}$$

We see that $f(n)$ oscillates between $-1$ for odd $n$ and $0$ for even $n$, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$ exists by the Leibniz criterion and can be shown to be given by $-A$.